# Empty .csv with headers shows count as '1'. When .csv has one entry, count still shows as '1'

Tags: powershell, csv

We have a .csv file with headers that is auto-populated daily with mobile devices enrolled into our MDM, yet are not entered into our device database.

I have script to parse the .csv, tag the devices in the console, and send out an email to the support team to investigate. The script performs a count of the rows, but runs into a problem when there is no data, meaning the rows are empty except for the headers. I'm guessing this is because the script has no data to perform actions against, yet when this happens, the count still shows as '1'.

When there is only one row populated with data, the count still shows as '1', however, always shows correct counts when more data (rows) is populated.

I'm guessing my best solution would be to simply code in a 'script kill switch', meaning if there is no data in the spreadsheet, the script should stop.

I also wanted to only send an email to support if there is data in the .csv file.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

I've tried many methods to count the rows, but when the spreadsheet is empty it still counts the header. The header is not counted when there are rows populated.

```
# Path to file
$NoICK = Import-Csv \\server\folder\TrueUp.csv

#Device Counts
$devicecount = ($NoICK | Measure-Object).Count 

# Creates a copy file and tags all devices (function not show here)
Foreach ($item in $NoICK){

    $noICK | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation 

    tag_NoICKregistration $item.device_id
}  

# Only send email to support if there are devices     
If ($devicecount -gt '0'){

    Send-MailMessage -From $smtpFrom -To $smtpTo -Subject $messageSubject -Body $body -SmtpServer $smtpServer
}
```

If the true count is zero, meaning no data was entered into the .csv file, I would like the script to stop after creating the copy, and to not send the email.

Comment: Cannot reproduce - when I have a CSV file with "headers only" then `Measure-Object` gives a count of 0.

Comment: I agree with @Tomalak , header only row gives me count of 0.

Comment: Your logic is correct, your CSV output must be different.  Thirding what the previous two commenters have said - `Measure-Object` shows 0 when only a header resides.  That said, what version of PowerShell are you running (`$PSVersionTable` shows me `5.0`)?

Comment: I'm going to have to agree that the .csv output must be different. Is there something that defines headers in a typical .csv file? I've tried just running the commands that imports and file and the count, again, always with '1' when no data entered.

Comment: I have also tested with other .csv files and had expected results of '0' when no data was entered. I've asked the person who generates this .csv to inspect how it's being created. I cannot reproduce with other files. One thing of note: When I enter the variable by itself, when no data is entered, i am presented with the headers and no data. When I change the path to other .csv files with no data and enter the variable, those don't show anything.

Comment: Show output from `Format-Hex -Path '\\server\folder\TrueUp.csv'`. Please [edit] the question rather than posting it in a comment.

Comment: Cannot Reproduce.  You will have to show us the content of one of your empty csv files.  The chances are it's not really empty, even if it has no printable characters after the header.  BTW,  the result of doing an Import-csv on a truly empty csv file is a $null value.  The count of a null value is 0.

Comment: What do get if you simply say  "$Noick.count"?